# How to change the bootstrap multiselect label instead of selected all?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using the bootstrap Multiselect drop-down instead of number of list showing when hit select  all option can we show the All Selected text.

http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Comment: post some code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to debug but it seems it uses direclty jquery.js. There isn't looking like custom content. It looks wrong but weird. If you can figure it out before 3 selections, you can extend it to 4,5,6 of course.

Answer (score 34):

If someone hit this question in the future , solution is change the

```
{ nonSelectedText: 'None selected' }
```

assign a global variable to this text change it through JavaScript.

value resides in bootstrap-multiselect.js file.

Comment: I'm glad a I scrolled down, this works perfectly. You can set `noneSelectedText` for each new multiselect object, if you have multiple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

You can change "Label" (of bootstrap multiselect) text for all 4 cases "none selected", "n selected", "All" Selected or "selected values" as follows:

JQuery

```
$('#level').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    maxHeight: 150,
    buttonWidth: 150,
    numberDisplayed: 2,
    nSelectedText: 'selected',
    nonSelectedText: 'None selected',
    buttonText: function(options, select) {
      var numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;
      if (options.length === 0) {
         return nonSelectedText + ' <b class="caret"></b>';
      }
      else{
             if (options.length > numberDisplayed) {
                 if(options.length === numberOfOptions){
                     return ' All Selected' + ' <b class="caret"></b>';
                 }
                 return options.length + ' ' + nSelectedText + ' <b class="caret"></b>';
             }else {
                 var selected = '';
                 options.each(function() {
                    var label = ($(this).attr('label') !== undefined) ?  
                                                       $(this).attr('label'):$(this).html();
                    selected += label + ', ';
                 });
                 return selected.substr(0, selected.length - 2) + ' <b class="caret"></b>';
             }
       }
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="level">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

It works for me. Have fun!

Comment: Somehow the all selected part does not work for me and fall into the nSelected part... Basically the options.length === numberOfOptions does not work as it should, I don't know what can be wrong.. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 8):

Use init obj options.

```
$("#services").multiselect({
  nonSelectedText:'Services'
});
```

This option worked for me.

Comment: There's a typo, the property is called `nonSelectedText`

Answer (score 7):

use **data-placeholder**

```
<select data-placeholder="Month">
```

This work for me.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working at all. Which version are you using?

Comment: Works on 1.1.2 at least.

Answer (score 6):

Following the [official documentation](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-allSelectedText):

> `allSelectedText` is the text displayed if all options are selected. You
>   can disable displaying the `allSelectedText` by setting it to false.

use option

```
{
...
allSelectedText: false,
...
}
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Answer (score 4):

Philip's answer worked for me, but just making it a bit more complete, it should be called upon document ready.  So the solution for me, including setting multiple lists was:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bedrooms").multiselect({
        nonSelectedText:'Bedrooms'
    });
    $("#bathrooms").multiselect({
        nonSelectedText:'Bathrooms'
    });
    $("#garages").multiselect({
        nonSelectedText:'Garages'
    });
    $("#livingareas").multiselect({
        nonSelectedText:'Living Areas'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed 3rd button's (**hint of button** : *Multiselect with a 'Select all' option*) id to **test**. It works but you need to add id to button from developer tools (Chrome / Firefox add F12) first.

```
$('#test+ul>li').change(function(){
    $('#test').text($('#test').attr('title'));
});
```

You can test it after you added the id. Please use jsfiddle.net after that. You may find help more quickly.